# Two-level header in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I created a new dataframe from an old one and now I have something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,5,1,1,3]}, index=[243,254,507,1903,2358]).rename_axis('uid')
print (df)
      0
uid    
243   1
254   5
507   1
1903  1
2358  3
```

I don't really understand what it means. Is that a double header with the first header having just one index and the second having the other one? How can I transform this dataframe into having a single header, with names `['userID' , 'counts']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one column `DataFrame` with column `0` and index name `uid`.

So need:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['userID' , 'counts']
print (df)
   userID  counts
0     243       1
1     254       5
2     507       1
3    1903       1
4    2358       3
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.rename_axis('userID').squeeze().reset_index(name='counts')
```